# How facebook contacts are stored in phone?

Tags: android, facebook, contacts, synchronization

My question is concerning the way that native facebook contacts are stored in phone, after full sync with usage of Facebook app. Is there any content provider to access them like with normal cotnacts. I am most concern about contacts from facebook which have phone number as a properity. I tried using content provider for contacts but it is not returing any of synchronized positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some reasearch I found out that access to FB content provider is restricted. Due to that there is no way to know what is user FB id in easy way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the contacts stored in the facebook application. The Facebook for iPhone app will synchronize your your friends' profile pictures and include a link to their profile in the native iPhone contact, but that's the extent of the information provided.

Comment: I am still thinking why did you anwser in iPhone maner? I was asking about Android OS.